# Spresense Arduino Library サンプルコードを元にしたwav形式のハイレゾオーディオ録音

Tags: arduino, spresense

**実現したいこと**

「8chデジタルマイクをSony Spresenseに接続し、
　Audio ライブラリでハイレゾ帯域（20KHz以上）の音を192KHzサンプリングで録音し、
　wav形式ファイルとしてSDカードに保存」

上記実現のためのステップ１として、以下は成功してます。

「ひとつのアナログマイクをSony Spresenseに接続し、
　可聴音（20KHz以下）の音を48KHzサンプリングで録音し、
　mp3形式ファイルとしてSDカードに保存」

Spresense Arduino Library 開発ガイドの手順通り、DSP Codec バイナリのインストールを行い、スケッチサンプルを入手してDSP ファイルがインストールされた場所の変更のみを行っています。
ここで入手したスケッチサンプルというのは以下です。
https://github.com/sonydevworld/spresense-arduino-compatible/tree/master/Arduino15/packages/SPRESENSE/hardware/spresense/1.0.0/libraries/Audio/examples/application/recorder

実現したいことに向けて、次のステップ2がうまくいきません。

「ひとつのアナログマイクをSony Spresenseに接続し、
　可聴音（20KHz以下）の音を48KHzサンプリングで録音し、
　wav形式ファイルとしてSDカードに保存」

録音実行はエラーコードも出ずに終了してwavファイルが出来上がるのですが、再生ができません。
以下はwindows Media Playerで再生した時のエラーメッセージです。

> ”ファイルを再生できません。プレーヤーがそのファイルの種類をサポートしていないか、
>   そのファイルの圧縮に使用したコーデックをサポートしていない可能性があります。”

ここでのコードは、上記スケッチサンプルから、
再生コンテンツのコーデックの種別設定を変更しています。
変更したコードの行は以下になります。

```
theAudio->setRecorderMode(AS_SETRECDR_STS_INPUTDEVICE_MIC_A);
theAudio->initRecorder(AS_CODECTYPE_PCM,"/mnt/spif/BIN",AS_SAMPLINGRATE_48000,AS_CHANNEL_MONO);
puts("Init Recorder!");
myFile = theSD.open("test.wav", FILE_WRITE);
```

**質問**

- wav録音するための、スケッチサンプルの変更箇所
- デジタルマイク入力のゲインを調整するAudio ライブラリ
- また、以下が少し気になります。対処方法ありますでしょうか。
  　Spresenseへのコード書き込みのたびに、Arduino IDE のメッセージエリアに
  　”ボードへの書き込みが完了しました”
  　とは表示されますが、テキストエリアに下記のワーニングが随時2行表示されます。
  　'Invalid version found: v1.0.2'

Answer (score 1):

## wavefileの破損について

変更後のプログラムのソースコードやwavefileのファイルサイズ、ヘッダ部のhexdumpなど、もう少し情報がほしいですね。
きちんとファイルは閉じましたか？　閉じない場合ファイルが破損する可能性があります。

## 余談

回答になってないかもしれませんが、spresenseはArduinoの開発はやる気がないみたいなのでSpresense SDKを用いた開発のほうがいいと思います。